# Estimating panel model in R

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, forecast

How can I estimate

$y_{i,t}=β_{i}x_{i,t}+ϵ_{i,t} \\
β_{i}=γ_{i}z_{i}+η_{i}$

in R ? Moreover, if I have splitted my data set to a train set which will contain 80% of all the i's and then I want to forecast the $y_{i,t}$ for the rest 20% i's  $\forall t$, how can I do it in R ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: The best package for panel data in R is [plm](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pglm/plm.pdf). You can find more info [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/147350/computing-the-predicted-value-from-a-panel-data-model-with-the-plm-r-package)

Answer (score 2):

For linear regression you want to use R's lm() function, like this:

```
my.model <- lm(response.variable ~ predictor1 + predictor2, data = my.data)
```

Look at the model using:

```
summary(my.model)
```

You can apply this model to a "test" dataset (your 20% split) by using predict(), like this:

```
predict(my.model, test.data)
```